# Conditional styling on row for dynamic cell value

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

Conditional row styling on ag grid where I want to do rowstyle on user choice of cell value

```js
gridoptions.getRowStyle = function(params) {
  if (params.node.data === 'cell value typed by user in external/custom component i.e outside grid') {
    return { 'background': value selected by user in cutom componet outside grid };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@sandeep's answer works perfectly. I just want to chime in another way to solve the problem which is to use [`context`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-context). `context` is just another javascript object which contains any information that you want to share within AgGrid. The data will be accessible in most AgGrid callbacks for example cell renderers, editors's render callback and in your case `getRowStyle` callback

```js
const sickDays = // data from external component
const color = // data from external component

<AgGridReact
  getRowStyle={(params) => {
    const { styles, data } = params.context;

    if (params.node.data["sickDays"] === data.sickDays) {
      return { backgroundColor: styles.color };
    }
    return null;
  }}
  context={{
    data: { sickDays },
    styles: { color }
  }}
/>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit AgGrid Context]

Answer (score 1):

here is a [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/GAUogo7VcOyyWGeu) which should give you idea to solve the problem. since i don't know much about your component hence i used two input boxes with button to set background color to row but you can use complex styles as well.

I am using `api.redrawRows()` since the operation we are performing needs to work on row.

[image: this is how it is working]

Comment: Thanks Sandeep Apologies not having my code on shared loaction. One more thing I want to know if we can pass values as arguments and use it in getrowstyle method as was not able to do that ?  I dont want to use document.getElementbyId

Comment: you can not pass extra arguments/variable in getRowStyle method but what you can do is, you can define a few variable outside that functions scope and can use those inside function.

Comment: right I was able to do that with variables. was checking if context works here or not.. I guess no..

Comment: I am an Angular Developer and we use services and other ways to share data between components and I know very little about context in react.(I only know that you can share data using context in React) So i know less about context than you. I guess you can explore. ;-)

Comment: @sandeepjoshi that's not true, you can pass extra arguments to `getRowStyle` via `params.context`

Comment: thanks for updating my knowledge regarding context.

Comment: Thanks @NearHuscarl & Sandeep